# Azure DevOps YAML Split & Each

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have variable group in Pipeline and it has below input

> Input: Instance1,Instance2,Inastance3
>
> Expected Output: Instance1 Instance2 Inastance3

We tried below YAML Code

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- group: "DevInstanceList"
- name: InstancesList
  value: $[variables.Instances]

steps:
- script: echo $(InstancesList) 
- ${{ each env in split(variables.InstancesList, ',')}}:
    - script: echo ${{ env }}
```

We tried to split using comma seperator and getting below error.

> Error: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is
> ".Instances")

Instance Defined in Library--> Group variable
[image]
Please share your thoughts

Comment: You can't loop over runtime variables, i.e. variables in `$[]`. `each` is evaluated at template compile time, which is **before** runtime variables exist. Where is `Instances` coming from?

Comment: This instance already defined in Library--> Variablegroup

Comment: @DanielMann Screenshot attached, Please check

Comment: @RamakrishnanRamar - If you are using a comma in between values, then use a comma in split function. Also do not use square brackets for this variable.

Comment: @DillyB, tried the same getting below Error: 2022-11-24T07:33:26.0927353Z echo $[variables.Instances]
2022-11-24T07:33:26.0928971Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2022-11-24T07:33:26.0973703Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/d165e9f5-6780-4eb8-8943-7e7caf2ed763.sh
2022-11-24T07:33:26.1025861Z /home/vsts/work/_temp/d165e9f5-6780-4eb8-8943-7e7caf2ed763.sh: line 1: variables.Instances: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".Instances")

Comment: @RamakrishnanRamar: I have updated my answer with images. Hope you are using variable groups to declare InstancesName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my test, the $[] cannot be fetched in compile time use for each. As @Daniel mentioned. If you are using '$(Instances)' in "each", you will find the empty.

For more information, you can refer to [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

So you can try to provide the value in the YAML file.

YAML like:

```
variables:
- group: "DevInstanceList"
- name: InstancesList
  value: Instance1,Instance2

steps:
- ${{ each env in split(variables.InstancesList, ',')}}:
    - script: echo ${{ env }}
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it's working. Could not find way to push dynamic variables. It's only taking defined variables. REST API also not allowing to update the Pipeline YAML.

Comment: I think you can try to use the object type of the parameters in the YAML pipeline, it can type the dynamic value before running pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script

Comment: Does it works in templates?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a powershell task like:

```
- powershell: |
   
   $results = "$(InstancesList)".Split(" ")
   $result[0]
   $result[1]
   $result[2]
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script to split variables'
```

Note: A space between double quotes in split function.
**Updated Answer: I Tested the code it works:**

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmimage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 - group: TestVariablegroup

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      echo $(InstancesName)
      $results = "$(InstancesName)".split(",")
      foreach ($instance in $results){
        Write-Host "The selected Instance Name is - $($Instance)"
      }
```

Adding variablegroup Image FYR:
[image: VariableGroup]

Adding Results Image FYR:
[image: Output Image]

Comment: That won't work for an `each` loop.

Comment: @DanielMann - Could you please let me know why the above does not work?

Comment: @DillyB is this possible to add - task: AzureFileCopy in for loop

Comment: @DillyB Tried this foreach ($instance in $results){
                  - steps:
                    - task: AzureFileCopy@3
                      inputs:
                        sourcePath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/build
                        azureSubscription: 'DEV'
                        destination: azureBlob
                        storage: - $($Instance)
                        containerName: "$web"
                        cleanTargetBeforeCopy: true
                } not working and returning Unexpected token 'task:' in expression or statement.

Comment: Azure File Copy was not part of your question. Sorry I haven't tried that. Also @Ging Yuan-MSFT answer also you can try. Another suggestion for you is instead of using tasks, convert that task as bash or powershell(your convenience) scripts. This will avoid dependency on tasks.

Comment: Because `each` loops are evaluated at **template compile time**. Anything that happens after the pipeline starts running is **after** template compilation.